# Using intro.js in multilingual angular 2 page

Tags: angular, intro.js, ng2-translate

I am developing a multilingual web page using angular 2 .
I wanted to add some guide for my users using intro.js ( consider that I am using the DefinitelyTyped library ) . it is okay when I write my guides in single language for example by this line :

```
<div  data-step="1"  data-intro="some text" >
```

but when I try to have multilingual guides using ng2-translate , I get nothing. here is my code :

```
<div data-step="1" data-intro=" 'dashboard.welcome' | translate " >
```

in data-intro property, I have tested combination of {{ }} , " " or ' ' to see if the syntax is wrong but none of them solved my problem. I wonder if some one can help me .